# Get 'SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred' when trying to run steam

Tags: steam

I'm on ubuntu 15.04.3. I've run sudo apt-get update, upgrade, distro-update etc., installed a bunch of 32-bit libraries, but I still can't get it to run. The full error is here:

SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, I've seen that today.

Running `~/.steam/steam.sh` yields a more verbose output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically                
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
awk: /home/niklas/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (requ
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
[2016-06-14 18:24:28] Startup - updater built Jun  9 2016 20:55:22                                                                 
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
^C
```

So - it's the old "Steam ships old versions of the libraries already existing on the system and they don't work"-problem.

It is fixable by running:

```
cd ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
rm amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib*
rm amd64/usr/lib/lib*
rm amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib*
rm i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lib*
rm i386/usr/lib/lib*
rm i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lib*
ldd steamclient.so 
#install those that are missing:
sudo apt install libnm-glib4:i386
```

It works now - until the next update....

(see https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/172#issuecomment-225929024)

Comment: I've seen it many times and this is what I used, it works great!

Comment: Yes, I've Seen this library bug a few times. But I don't remember this message coming from the updater UI and that the original errors are being hidden.