# steam won't run (different error)

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, vmware, steam, thinkpad

this is a duplicate of [Get 'SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred' when trying to run steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648905/get-steamupdateui-an-x-error-occurred-when-trying-to-run-steam), but that hasn't seen any activity since first post back in July 2015... So, here we go again.

could not find steam proper in USC, so followed instructions in [In software center, some softwares are not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451306/in-software-center-some-softwares-are-not-found), able to install, run steam, starts updates, go to bathroom, come back, update bar gone, sitting on homepage like nothing happened. click steam, nothing happens, run steam through terminal, get:

```
Startup - updater built Mar 10 2016 10:39:59
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Ubuntu 15.10 on VMWare Workstation 12 Player. Just wanting to verify everything works before switching over completely. not wanting to dual boot in laptop. no intent to really play any games on laptop, as Thinkpad 20DQ-001MUS has issues with smart switching graphics card to save power when fancy 3d graphics not needed. a little frustrated to find that out after the fact, but ya know. debating on switching desktop to ubuntu and buying new laptop. Anyway, Steam won't run. And I get that error when running in terminal. Help?

Going to try NVidia settings to force graphics card for VMWare, but not hopeful, as I mainly use this for school anyway. And pretty sure that wouldn't work if dual boot (not enough space for dual boot anyway, Windows 10 is huge when using OneDrive... And that's after limiting it to not include many folders).